# IndexError Out of bounds for Graphic Element

Tags: arcpy, indexerror

I have this error that I'm confused on how to resolve getting this North arrow graphic element from the map document.

Code:

```
result = arcpy.mapping.ConvertWebMapToMapDocument(Web_Map_as_JSON, templateMxd, noteGDB )
mapDoc = result.mapDocument
export(mapDoc, pdfPaths)

   # reset map variable to point to a new map document based on the mxd path passed into it
def getMap(templateMxdForPopup):
    global mapDoc
    del mapDoc
    print "Map Doc will be:" + templateMxdForPopup
    mapDoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(templateMxdForPopup)

getElements(mapDoc)
#graphic element
def getElements(mapDocBeingPassed):
  graphicElm = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mapDocBeingPassed, "GRAPHIC_ELEMENT", "north_arrow")
  if (graphicElm.count > 0):
    northArrow = graphicElm[0]
```

Error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Workspace-TT\pythonprint\customPrint.py", line 248, in <module>
>     getMap(templateMxd)   File "C:\Workspace-TT\pythonprint\customPrint.py", line 178, in getMap
>     getElements(mapDoc)   File "C:\Workspace-TT\pythonprint\customPrint.py", line 221, in getElements
>     northArrow = graphicElm[0] IndexError: list index out of range
> 
> Failed to execute (CustomPrint).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer why I am getting an Index Out of Bound Error. The north arrow is a map surround element and not a graphic element.

```
# mapsurround element ==> refers to the north arrow 
mapSurroundElm = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mapDocBeingPassed, "MAPSURROUND_ELEMENT", "north_arrow") if (mapSurroundElm.count > 0):
northArrow = mapSurroundElm[0]
```